# Calculating width of a line in a paragraph using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

For example I have a paragraph

```
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat</p>
```

And I also have defined its style in css

```
.text { width:20em; }
```

The text align is **not justified**, so the width of each line may not be the same.

Now how can I **calculate the width of each line separately**?

Comment: Refer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: @BenjaminRay Your edit(s) are begin discussed here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289145/same-one-letter-edit-suggested-to-nearly-60-questions-should-i-alert-a-moderato?cb=1